# How can I access VO in one application module from a VO in another application module?

Tags: java, oracle, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I have two Application Modules in the same project and in the same directory. I want to access a VO in first application module from a VO in second application module. How can that be done?

Comment: If it's on the same project, you have access to the class. Can you try doing some java like MyVoClass vo = new MyVoClass() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Application Module Instances :

- Right Click on Model Project Then go to Project Properties
- Go To ADF Business Components  - >  Application Module Instances
- Add your targeted Application Module
- Then you can add a View Object instance to the Application Module to
  from another Application Module

**See the link below :**

https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/adf/ADFFD/bclookups.htm#ADFFD1594